# Multiple AdditionalPageHead overloads

Tags: 2013, delegate-control

I have a requirement where I have 6 different jQuery snippets which I have included in 6 different user controls.

And I have 6 different features which override the delegate control with these 6 UserControls. When

I need to activate these 6 scripts with different combinations on different sites.

When I activate a single control, it works fine. But when I activate any 2, the one with higher sequence number starts coming twice.

Is there a way to solve this issue.

My requirement is to activate features in combination which introduces different scripts on page.

Comment: Can you update question with relevant code/xml.

Comment: @AmalHashim it would be very long. I am asking for a correct approach and not to correct on what I am doing